# I heard inspecific is not a correct English word, but I find in some circumstances it makes more sense than alternatives

Tags: antonyms

For example, if you were to say that something is particular to only one race, you'd say the trait is "race-specific". So my question is, what is the opposite of this? I would say it's "race-inspecific", since that sounds correct to me and "race-unspecific" doesn't seem to make sense. Neither does "race-nonspecific".

Edit:
I think the word I was looking for is "dependent" and "independent".

Comment: One thing is for sure: inspecific is not a word.

Comment: Merriam Webster Online has entries for both [unspecific](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unspecific) and [nonspecific](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonspecific) but no entry for _inspecific_. Why do you think that the two listed words don't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think usually, using your example, you would say 'non-specific to race', 'independent of race', or maybe 'race-independent' (although the last one doesn't sound quite right).

Perhaps use 'non-race-specific'?

Comment: Can you cite sources for these uses?